# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function?

Tags: magento2, fatal-error

I have **namespace\module\Block\Display.php**:

```
 <?php

 namespace Magento\History\Block;

 class Display extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {    

    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(

          \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
        ) 
        {

            $this->productRepository = $productRepository;

         }
    public function getProductBySku($sku)
    {
        $order = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) 
        {  
            echo $item->getName();
        }
    }
}
```

And in this file .phtml, I have :

```
<?php
 $order = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\History\Block\Display');
 echo $order->getProductBySku();
?>
```

When I run, I have this error: 
[image]

**Can anyone help? Thanks**

Comment: `echo $order->getProductBySku($sku);` you have to pass `sku` in function as argument

Comment: what is your task or what you want using this code ???

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getProductBySku($sku)
```

As we can see, your function needs an argument. 
I also have a note that your block class is missing the parent constructor from `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`.

Comment: @all. Thanks for your help. How can I fix this error???